# PHP + MySQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

```
if ($_POST) {$content = stripslashes($_POST['content']);
    $by = $_SESSION['exp_user']['username'];
    $dt = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 
    mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_intmsg SET time = ".$dt.", by = ".$by." AND content = ".$content."") or die(mysql_error());
```

For which I recieve error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
>   right syntax to use near '26, 2009, 2:28 pm, by = 
>   shamil.nunhuck AND content = 
>   Test message!
>   ' at line 1

Any ideas?

Comment: Errors like this are easier to troubleshoot if you examine the resulting SQL string, not the code that produces that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah scrap that, here's the answer:

```
$db = mysql_query("UPDATE `tbl_intmsg` SET `time` = '".$dt."', `by` = '".$by."', `content` = '".$content."'");
```

Comment: How is it SQL-injectable? If you're going to downvote, at least give me more. EDIT: I've removed the escaping becuase I'm using a custom class to do it.

Comment: `$content` comes from `$_POST['content']` with no escaping, custom classes for escaping are a recipe for disaster. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` and nothing else.

Comment: See the edit to above, I've removed the escaping because it was adding unnecessary stuff to the question.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider sanitizing your input with the intended function as well:

```
mysql_real_escape_string()
```

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Added a link to the docs for you, and +1 to help you get the reputation needed to add links. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah your SQL looks like this when it is being read by the MySQL server:

```
UPDATE tbl_intmsg SET time = 26, 2009, 2:28 pm, by = shamil.nunhuck 
    AND content = Test message!
```

How is MySQL to figure out what is what in that statement?

Imagine, for instance, that you set your $content to '0 WHERE dummy = true'. Then your SQL would look like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_intmsg SET time = 26, 2009, 2:28 pm, by = shamil.nunhuck 
    AND content = 0 WHERE dummy = true
```

Do you see the problem? How is SQL to figure out what is your data, and what is SQL keywords?

The answer is: quotes!

Your SQL should look like this:

```
UPDATE tbl_intmsg SET time = '26, 2009, 2:28 pm', by = 'shamil.nunhuck' 
    AND content = 'Test message!'
```

Your PHP SQL-query string could look like this:

```
$q="UPDATE tbl_intmsg SET time = '$dt', by = '$by' AND content = '$content'";
```

(Note that PHP parses double-quote strings for variables and replaces them with their value. Also note that you should use the above mentioned function

```
mysql_real_escape_string($var)
```

to sanitize your data before putting it into MySQL. Here's the link that mechler couldn't post: [php.net/mysql-real-escape-string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string))

Cheers!

/0

Answer (score 1):

put SQL quotes around your string variables:

```
UPDATE tbl_intmsg SET time = \"".$dt."\", by = \"".$by."\" AND content = \"".$content."\"
```